# Using Core Data for App Settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, settings

Is it be considered bad practice to use Core Data to manage in app settings? For example, I create an entity called "Settings", and give it an attributes like "preferred theme", or "sort by:", then when I want to access the settings, in the viewWillAppear method of a view controller, I fetch the entity, and use the attribute values. Is that inefficient/ is there a better way to do this?

Comment: http://nshipster.com/nscoding/ Depends.  There may be other, better options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` is the preferred method of storing and retrieving app settings (see the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html) )

CoreData will work for app settings, but is in general overkill. The main reason I can think of for using CoreData for settings is to synchronize over iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to store a light weight data , then you can use **NSUserDefaults** or **NSCoder**. Core data is only preferred for a large amount of data. It is more complex than the above options.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/nscoding-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-save-your-app-data